# Can I use a keyboard for Apple?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

I want to buy a mobile Bluetooth keyboard.  It seems Apple ones are easier to find.
Does it make much difference?

(I assume the connection is the same for similar models, and the issue is layout)

[image: One of the models I am looking at. Looks the same for Android and Apple]

Comment: Do you have an Apple Store or Kiosk near you? If so, they likely have the BT keyboards on display and you could test them directly to see if it'll work. Otherwise you could check out the specific sub-forum for your phone at [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) and ask about the mac keyboards there...Unfortunately different phones can use different Bluetooth stacks so a Mac keyboard that works with one Android phone, doesn't necessarily mean it will work with another.

Comment: I was thinking of similar models, like "Logitech Tablet Keyboard (Keyboard-and-Stand Combo) for iPad, iPad 2, iPad (3rd/4th generation), and iPad mini (920-003241)" and "Logitech 920-003390 Tablet Keyboard for Android 3.0 Plus".
Android version above.

Comment: (Regarding holding).  If I think Apple layout can be annoying, I am less likely to buy a keyboard for Apple, but its not really purchasing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a couple of different BlueTooth keyboards and they all work pretty well on Android. I would assume the Apple keyboards would work just as well. I am a fan of Logitech keyboards just because I've always used them and they have always worked. You can always just buy an Apple keyboard and if it doesn't work you can just return it.